Are potted roses safe outside in monsoon?
I procured and potted some roses in March and now its monsoon.
Needless to say they are getting more water than I would normally give them.
Is it safe for them? If the roses in the ground can survive monsoon, can potted roses too?

Yes, your potted roses can be safe during the monsoon, but a few things that you have to make sure of are the proper drainage of the pot and prevent waterlogging, and regularly keeping a check on the bottom of the plant to make sure that it doesn't sit in pooled water, Be on alert for any warning signs of fungal infections or any other illness, For better air circulation trim your roses and remove if any leave turns yellow or dead.
And if possible move the plant to a place that is slightly sheltered or where it doesn't get excessive rain.

Yes, they are totally safe you can go ahead.
